# scan image, create links from content (php hopefully)

Tags: image, hyperlink, overlay, scanning

I'm not sure if this could work, but I've got pictures of maps with #'s inside a little box on top of the map to show locations. See my image example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf1p3.png]

I'm hoping to find a script to 'scan' the image and create links from the number locations (and overlay those links where the boxes are)

In the image example, all the boxes have a 3 in them, but on the other maps they may go from 1 to 400.  So I'm hoping to be able to get a link overlay on the boxes sending to another image.  Ie, map box #3 would create a link such as `http://www.example.com/images/image3.jpg` when hovered over.  (as long as I can take the # in the box and stuff it in a link over the box.

Comment: I don't know if you can do it automated like you want, but you sure can do it manually (all info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: It should be possible. However it would involve several complex algorithms to scan for boxes and then OCR the numbers - assuming all boxes have the same format and color and use the same font, it is quite doable. That kind of computation is something you really don't want to do in a PHP script, especially not for each request.

Comment: Hmm.  I checked out the tag_map, that might work, but a pain to repeat over for each map I have.  It doesn't have to be PHP (that's what my site uses though).  I make the maps up in ms publisher, the map is the background and then I drag and drop the #'d boxes over the right area.  I wish I could save as webpage and have links.  Any other ideas?  A script or something that produced the html <map> tags from publisher would be sweet.  I had originally hoped to have css div tags as the # boxes, then I could glow them or do various things depending on user selection.