# jquery, dynamically create link from text in td cell

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink, cell, html-table

I have a question currently up at:
[scan image, create links from content (php hopefully)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890512/scan-image-create-links-from-content-php-hopefully)

Since I'm working in ms publisher, I can remove the map image and just keep the #'d boxes.  Saving just those as .htm I end up with the following code:

```
<!--[if gte vml 1]><![if mso | ie]><v:shape id="_x0000_s1039" type="#_x0000_t201" style='position:absolute;left:311.27pt;top:110.81pt;width:11.34pt;height:9pt; z-index:7;mso-wrap-distance-left:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:2.88pt; mso-wrap-distance-right:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:2.88pt' stroked="f" strokecolor="black [0]" insetpen="t" o:cliptowrap="t">
<v:stroke color2="white [7]">
<o:left v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" weight="0"/>
<o:top v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" weight="0"/>
<o:right v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" weight="0"/>
<o:bottom v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" weight="0"/>
<o:column v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
</v:stroke>
<v:shadow color="#ccc [4]"/>
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
</v:textbox>
</v:shape><![endif]><![endif]-->

<table v:shapes="_x0000_s1039" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=15 height=12 border=0 dir=ltr style='width:11.34pt;height:9.0pt;border-collapse:collapse; position:absolute;top:110.81pt;left:311.27pt;z-index:7'>
<tr>
<td width=15 height=12 bgcolor=white style='width:11.3385pt;height:9.0pt; padding-left:.1417pt;padding-right:.1417pt;padding-top:.1417pt;padding-bottom:.1417pt;background:white;border:solid blue .25pt'>
<p class=MsoNormal style='text-align:center;text-align:center'><span lang=en-US style='font-size:5.0pt;font-family:Arial;language:en-US'><span dir=ltr></span>185</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking (as in the previous question) to create links from the #'s in the cell (in this instance it is 185.  I have far too many to manually do this on an ongoing basis, so am searching for a way to do it with code.

I found this code with jQuery which should grab the text from the :

```
 $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
     var 
    $tds = $(this).find('td');
     if($tds.length != 0) {
     var 
    $currText = $tds.eq(0).text();

    alert('Curr Source Language: ' + $currText);

     }
     });
```

I'm not quite sure how to implement the jQuery above either.  I would like the entire table to be a link (not just the inner #'s).  So if the 'get  text' works, then I'd like to wrap the entire table with:
    
     
      [-- everything inbetween as above code --](http://gotothislink_185.jpg)

I hope that makes some sense.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way of finding the value in the table im using `lang=en-US` as a selector.
Then you need to build a url and change the page

```
$(function (){
        // Assign click event on any table
        $('table').click(function(){
           // Get Value
           var val = $(this).find('[lang=en-US]').text();
           // Change Page
           window.location.href = "http://gotothislink_" + val + ".jpg"
        });
});
```

Working example 
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/tSMnd/

Comment: looks easy and works great (i think) when I follow your jsfiddle link.  I can't seem to figure out how to get it to load.  my test page is at http://www.madeus.info/test.htm  could you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: you simply click where it says 185, and you see it will load http://gotothislink.... which of course will 404

Comment: you need to wrap the script inside a document ready function $(document).ready(function(){ //code here   });

Comment: Thanks very much Blowsie.  Works great and gives me a place to start from.

Comment: Does work great.  I'm trying to fit the page inside a webpage template that also has it's own tables.  Is there a way I can confine the table.click.function to a certain <div>?

Comment: Everything was working well, then I added some code elsewhere and it started adding all the numbers from all tables to each link.  I removed all the code I changed (like 6 times), saved uploaded tested etc. and I can't get it back to normal.  I flushed my cache, tried different browsers. Hmm.. any idea why the each link would be like:

Comment: http://gotothislink_146175176185387388400401144145147148149152154157158159163164165166167168169170171172173174177178179180182183186187188189190192193194195196197198199201202203204205206292293294295296297300301302303382384385386390391392393394395398399402406408479143160381383397404405.jpg/  instead of just "185.jpg"?  Each table's number is a max 3 digits, the first table in the code is 146, and the last is 405.  it's merging all of them together.

Comment: i'm sure it's because i've got it wrapped in nested tables.

Comment: Sounds most likely, try changing $('table') to $('.MsoNormal')

Comment: Awesome :)  it works, thanks so much!  Works for switching the cursor (.MsoNormal { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }) properly too.