# Replacing DataTable content with links

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a basic DataTable in my view. One of the table columns shows phone numbers. All the numbers I will have to deal with are exactly ten digits without any formatting (like dashes or parentheses).

I would like to replace all these numbers with a link that has this phone number in it.

How would I go about doing this?

---

I tried something based on this question:
[jquery, dynamically create link from text in td cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928769/jquery-dynamically-create-link-from-text-in-td-cell)

I replaced the code to have a regex for just ten digits. This is the scripting I call immediately after my HTML table which has `id="mydata"`. The view only contains this table and the scripting:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#mydata').click(function(){
        var phone = $(this).find(/\d{10}/).text();
        window.location.href = "http://somelink" + phone + ".jpg"
      });

      $('#mydata').DataTable( {
        deferRender:    true,     // Renders only the rows that are visible
        dom:            'frtiS',  // Additional parameters. See docs. 
        scrollCollapse: true,     // Collapses table if there are few results
        scrollY:        700       // Height of the container
      } );
    } );
  </script>
```

Unfortunately, here the functions seems to trigger regardless of where I click in the table, and does not embed the phone number within the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column that contains only phone numbers then you can use [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) option to target specific column and define a [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) callback function that will be called when data in that column needs to be rendered.

**SOLUTION 1: Render data in a single column**

For example, if the second column (`targets: 1`, indexes are zero-based) contains phone numbers, use the code below:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#mydata').DataTable( {
    deferRender:    true,     // Renders only the rows that are visible
    dom:            'frtiS',  // Additional parameters. See docs. 
    scrollCollapse: true,     // Collapses table if there are few results
    scrollY:        700,       // Height of the container
    columnDefs: [
       {
          targets: 1,
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){
             if(type === 'display'){               
                return '<a href="http://somelink' + data + '.jpg">' + data + '</a>';
             } else {
                return data;
             }
          }
       }
    ]
  } );
} );
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etjtm8d9/1/) for demonstration.

---

**SOLUTION 2: Render data in all columns**

To render data in all columns, even when phone number is only part of the data, use the code below.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#mydata').DataTable( {
    deferRender:    true,     // Renders only the rows that are visible
    dom:            'frtiS',  // Additional parameters. See docs. 
    scrollCollapse: true,     // Collapses table if there are few results
    scrollY:        700,       // Height of the container
    columnDefs: [
       {
          targets: "_all",
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){
             if(type === 'display'){               
                return return data.replace(/(\d{10})/, "<a href=\"http://somelink$1.jpg\">$1</a>");
             } else {
                return data;
             }
          }
       }
    ]
  } );
} );
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etjtm8d9/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works really nicely if I know which column contains the phone number. What would I need to do if this wasn't known to me? I don't always know which column (or if any) have phone numbers, which was why I went with the regex approach.

Comment: @Azarantara, added another example for regex approach with all columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `columnDefs` property of the `DataTable`. Please see my basic example below. Obviously you will need to change the "targets" property to point to the index of the column which contains your telephone numbers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#mydata').DataTable({
    deferRender: true, // Renders only the rows that are visible
    dom: 'frtiS', // Additional parameters. See docs. 
    scrollCollapse: true, // Collapses table if there are few results
    scrollY: 700, // Height of the container
    "columnDefs": [{
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        return '<a href="http://somelink/' + data + '.jpg">' + data + '</a>';
      },
      "targets": 1
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<table id="mydata">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone no</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention rails in your question, but you tagged your questions with rails. So here is a rails/ruby solution. Normally phone number links will initiate a phone call instead of linking to a file/other site, so I switched the link from the jpeg file to initiate a phone call but you could use the same logic to create the jpeg file instead.

In the view I call a helper method:

```
<td><%= phone_number_link(@user.number) %></td>
```

In helper

```
def phone_number_link(phone_number)
  sets_of_numbers = phone_number.scan(/[0-9]+/)   #only needed if you may have ( or -'s
  number = "+1-#{sets_of_numbers.join('-')}"
  link_to phone_number, "tel:#{number}"
end
```

Or a rails specific solution if you want to create the call:

```
<td><%= link_to number_to_phone(text), "tel:#{number_to_phone(text, country_code: 1)}" %></td>
```

This probably should also be moved to a helper method, such as:

```
def phone_number_link(number)
  link_to number_to_phone(number), "tel:#{number_to_phone(number, country_code: 1)}"
end
```